# Blank context menu issue when there is no context item/menu to show

Tags: angular, contextmenu, ngx-contextmenu

I have used ngx-context menu with different condition using [visible] but in some condition i am not showing any context menu then blank menu is coming which need to hide . i have tried with *ngIf condition but some context-menu internal error came in the console,

```
<context-menu>
<ng-template [visisble]="condition" contextMenuItem (execute)="getCall($event)">Context menu 1</ng-template>
<context-menu>
```

please find screenshot and suggest me some solution Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you also share the error?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with [disabled] on context-menu. Add condition to hide or show menu accordingly.